# Subprocess issue on the linux

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I just created a script in python. Its working fine on Windows operation system locally.However, when I deploy my script to Linux Server. it gives the following errors; Is there any ideas to solve this issue on the linux ?

```
Typerror: execv arg 2 must contain only strings

    def export(ip, channel_search_list):


    if len(ip) > 0: 

            filename = "files//"+"output"+str(ip)+".txt"
            action = 'FullExport'
            menu_action = 'all'
            arg_list = [('upnp//Client//UPNP_Client_Cmd_Line.py')]

            arg_list.append(' --action=')
            arg_list.append(action)
            arg_list.append(' --ip=')
            arg_list.append(ip)
            arg_list.append(' --menu=')
            arg_list.append(menu_action)

            x = subprocess.Popen(arg_list, shell=True)

            print arg_list

            with open(filename, "w+") as output:
                subprocess.call(["python", arg_list], stdout=output)

    get_book_ids_func(filename, channel_search_list, ip)


File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "index.py", line 202, in export
    subprocess.call(['python', arg_list], stdout=output)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
PID is:4439
```

Comment: arg_list.append(str(ip)) ?

Comment: Hi @MauriceMeyer Thanks for your answer. I tried that before, unfortunately that did not solve the issue.

Comment: arg_list = [('upnp//Client//UPNP_Client_Cmd_Line.py')] contains a tuple and not a string

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>                subprocess.call(["python", arg_list], stdout=output)
> ```

Here we got a list of a string and a list, not a list of strings.
In order to prepend the 'str' `"python"` to the 'list' `arg_list`, we can write:

```
                subprocess.call(["python"]+arg_list, stdout=output)
```